# postgresql partitioning by date from existing table

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I need to partition an existing table which is main.customer by year. The situation I have is that, I have a column that contains a string with year in it and I want to extract the year part from that string.

my sample query is..

```
CREATE TABLE main.customer_prtn (LIKE main.customer)
PARTITION BY RANGE (to_date(substring(ref_id,1,4),'YYYY'))
(START (date '2008') INCLUSIVE,
....
END (date '2015') EXCLUSIVE
EVERY (INTERVAL '1 year') );
```

When I run the query, i get the message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2: PARTITION BY RANGE (to_date(substring(ref_id,1,4),'YYYY'))
```

Comment: You really should clarify your question!

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't have *declarative partitioning* yet (a [patch for v10](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/12/611/) is under review).

Read [the documentation about partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) to find out how it has to be done currently.